# Highlight Liquid with Rouge & Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, liquid, rouge

I am trying to highlight a block of liquid and html code, but it doesnt seem to be working. All other languages work fine.

i am using Jekyll v3.8.5 and the Rouge version in gemfile.lock is v3.3.0

I have been wrapping the code blocks in `{% highlight xxx %} - {% endhighlight %}` without any issues for other languages.

Below is what I am using currently

```
{% highlight liqiud %}

{% if project.tags.size > 0 %}
    {% for tag in project.tags %}
        <span class="project-tags text-lower text-monospace">{{ tag }}</span>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}

{% endhighlight %}
```

The below block highlights without any issues, it just seems to be anything with liquid in it that doesnt work.

```
{% highlight css %}

.project-tags, .post-tags {
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    color: #0366d6;
    background-color: #f1f8ff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 .5em .5em 0;
    padding: .3em .9em;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

{% endhighlight %}
```

For the liquid block,​ I just get an empty code block. These are my `_config.yml` settings:

```
kramdown:
  syntax_highlighter: rouge
  syntax_highlighter_opts:
    css_class: 'highlight'
    span:
      line_numbers: false
    block:
      line_numbers: true
```

I'm not going to lie I am a bit stumped.

Answer (score 3):

```
{% highlight liqiud %}
```

Could it be that you misspelled `liquid`?

Comment: the correct spelling didnt work...but i changed it to ```liquid which then worked. Thanks for pointing out my lack of spelling skills lol.